# XMLUnit-2 compare partial XMLs

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I have a local `test` XML data as below

**testLocalXML**

```
<root>
  <elementA>something different</elementA>
  <elementB>something else</elementB>
  <elementC>yet another thing</elementC>
</root>
```

but the data I'm getting from server could be large and will keep dynamically increasing e.g.

**Server Response**

```
<root>
  <elementA>something different</elementA>
  <elementB>something else</elementB>
  <elementC>yet another thing</elementC>
  <elementD>next data</elementD>
  <elementE>another data</elementE>
  <elementF>F data</elementF>
  .
  .
  ... so on...
</root>
```

I don't know which `node` I can ignore using below logic. My node are dynamic.

```
.withNodeFilter(node -> !(node.getNodeName().equals("elementD") ||
                          node.getNodeName().equals("elementE"))
```

Here, as server response is dynamic and keep on increasing how would I validate whatever data I mentioned in the **testLocalXML** using `XMLUnit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do know the elements that I'm interested in, so I could easily do

```
  final Collection<String> expected = Arrays.asList("root", "elementA", elementB", "elementC");
```

And can add filter as

```
  .withNodeFilter(n -> expected.contains(n.getNodeName()))
```